# How does Github store commit messages?

Tags: git, github, commit

I am trying to build an open source version control system using git. I want to give a search to users like Github to its users.
Like on Github users can search everything from files, users and commits. 
My question is how Github is storing commit so it can be searchable? Are the commits store in some database? Because it searches a single word of the commit from many repositories

I had attached a sample link of GitHub, you can see 2 million commits found. How does this search work?

[sample search link](https://github.com/search?q=sms)

Comment: Github uses `git` to store commits and commit messages. Github might do some kind of indexing, but I suggest you learn about how `git` stores objects first and then build on top of that.

Comment: Adding to the comment from @Code-Apprentice, git is more of a file system than a database. Check out [Understanding Git](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHkLxts9Mu4) on Youtube by Paolo Perrotta to learn more.

Comment: Dave Sexton, thank you for your feedback, I knew git is a file system. But searching in the file system and the compiling up the results is difficult. 
Assume there are 1000 repos and I want to search word 'X' so it is hard to go into 1000 repos and search the word X. I beleive github is using some database for do this.

What are your thoughts ?

Comment: GitLab is open source so you can [read](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab) their code.

Answer (score 0):

`git` stores commits, commit messages, and all the other objects it uses to do its job under the `.git` subfolder in your project's directory. GitHub leverages git to do much of the heavy lifting. I suggest that you learn about the internals of git and then build on top of that.

Comment: this is not the answer to my question